# Item fulfillment search kit/package items

Tags: netsuite

While performing Item fulfillment search, if mainline is false and there are kit/package items at the line-level, the search results shows the items as well as its components. Is there any filter that we can hide the component items of the kit item in that search?

Comment: Hi @Saurabh More, have you been able to test using my suggested answer? Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a way to use a filter to remove the kit/package components if you're searching directly for an `Item Fulflilmment` record.

My trick is to create a Transaction Saved Search but instead of filtering by the `Internal ID` or `Document Number`, use the `Fulfilling/Receiving Transaction` filter and then select the `Item Fulfillment` record you need results from.

By doing this, your results are actually referencing the the `Sales Order` record that the `Fulfillment` was created from, **and this doesn't show kit components!**

Then, in the results tab make sure to select `Fulfilling/Receiving Transaction fields...` and add the columns you need (such as `Item` and `Quantity`) to get the information from the `Item Fulfillment` record.

### **Here is an example:**

[image: Criteria Tab Selections]

[image: Results Tab Selections]